# resend user login & password with custom button

Tags: password, wp-mail

How would you resend the login & password to a user who has forgotten his password? In this case they don't want to go to the "password" forgotten page.

Additional Q: Mass re-sending of passwords.

I understand that it's nearly impossible to resend the password, so reset is also ok. but i need a way to click select some users and then send them the reset link mail.

Current Solution:
I list my users (ordered by role) in a table & simply added a little lost password form with a button. It works but is the opposite of ... nice. If you want to resend a password, you click the button and open a blank tab/window. This saves me from going back all time, but re-sending 200 password mails still is a pain. Plus: It's impossible to resend the password. The user just receives a link to click to reset the password.

```
<td id="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>;user_pass;<?php echo $wpdb->users;?>">
    <form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword'); ?>" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input hide" value="<?php echo $curuser->user_login; ?>" size="15" tabindex="10" />
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="reset-pass" class="margin-null" value="send" tabindex="100" />
    </form>
</td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked out some of the available plugins for ideas? ie. [exhibit #1](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reset-all-user-passwords/) and [exhibit #2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulk-password-reset/) ...

Comment: ehm. no. it was an older project and back then there was nothing available. didn't know and therefore not search. thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: @t31os Could you add the second link as answer, so i can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the passwords for all users use the plugin [Bulk Password Reset](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulk-password-reset/).
It offers a nice interface with some useful options. For example: You can choose the users by their role or add a custom message to the reset email.